# Mariadb Python Module Type Hinting for Contextmanager Cursor

Tags: python, mariadb, type-hinting, contextmanager

I cannot discern the correct typing for this. How can I figure out what this should be?

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

import mariadb


@contextmanager
def mariadb_con(
        user: str,
        password: str,
        host: str,
        database: str,
        port: int,
        commit: bool = False
        ) -> mariadb.connection.cursor:
    con = mariadb.connect(
            user=user,
            password=password,
            host=host,
            database=database,
            port=port
            )
    cur = con.cursor()
    yield cur
    if commit is True:
        con.commit()
    cur.close()
    con.close()
```

When I try to use the context_manager with this typing it returns:

```
AttributeError: module 'mariadb' has no attribute 'connection'
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing around I found this:

```
mariadb._mariadb.connection.cursor
<method 'cursor' of 'mariadb.connection' objects>
```

Which appears to seems to be the cursor method of the connection class.

This looks correct after printing it's type:

```
print(type(mariadb._mariadb.connection.cursor))
<class 'method_descriptor'>
```

I then added this to the contextmanager. Perhaps someone with more experience can tell me if this is a misunderstanding.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from typing import Generator

import mariadb


@contextmanager
def mariadb_con(
        user: str,
        password: str,
        host: str,
        database: str,
        port: int,
        commit: bool = False
        ) -> Generator[mariadb._mariadb.connection.cursor, None, None]:
    con = mariadb.connect(
            user=user,
            password=password,
            host=host,
            database=database,
            port=port
            )
    cur = con.cursor()
    yield cur
```